# how to make running activity disable while progress bar running in java android

Tags: java, android

i have an activity or screen which contains mainly 3 views (ex.textview1,textview2,textview3) and a progress bar.

While progress bar running or loading if i click on either of textview1,textview2,textview3,
corresponding next activity or screen is opening.

But i want like while progress bar running relevant screen should disable(not tappable) or should not move to next screen if i click on any of these views.

please reply with an example

Answer (score 0):

Just create a boolean for when the you have something in progress and then check for it in you onClickListener.

```
boolean isRunning;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(isRunning)
        return;

    //handle code normally


}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. is there any way to just disable whole activity or screen while progress bar loading till progress bar completes loading

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog That's probably what you're looking for. It will block the user from doing anything else while it's on screen.

Comment: thanks for the reply. as i'm new to android i'm not getting answer from this also .please provide alternate solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class to do this

FYI, AsyncTask is known as [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) in Android.

```
onCreate() {
  ...

  MyTask task = new MyTask();
  task.execute();

}

class MyTask extends AsyncTask
{
  onPreExecute() { 
     // disable your views here
  }

  doInBackground() {
     // do your loading here in background
  }

  onPostExecute() {
    // enable your views to start activities
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. is there any way to just disable whole activity or screen while progress bar loading till progress bar completes loading